# CRM 2011 Online - On Save or exit error message "<Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id)"

Tags: javascript, dynamics-crm-2011

After the last rollup of Microsoft CRM 2011 Online (version 5.0.9690.5010) started to give this error, i have disabled everything that was javascript and continues to give me this. Whether we close a window or either on save.

I also used the steps on this URLS: https://community.dynamics.com/crm/f/117/t/103854.aspx#.UkQ7doakoSx
and as is written on the post "Even native CRM javascript functions are not working."
Same issue for me! Is It better to open a ticket with the Microsoft Technical Support team?

Error messsage:

```
    <CrmScriptErrorReport>
  <ReportVersion>1.0</ReportVersion>
  <ScriptErrorDetails>
   <Message>Expected ';'</Message>
   <Line>1</Line>
   <URL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?_gridType=1&etc=1&id=%7b9CD0EF13-9226-E311-A991-D4856451CC85%7d&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1380202069365&rskey=571248839</URL>
   <PageURL>/userdefined/edit.aspx?_gridType=1&etc=1&id=%7b9CD0EF13-9226-E311-A991-D4856451CC85%7d&pagemode=iframe&preloadcache=1380202069365&rskey=571248839</PageURL>
   <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","</Function>
   <CallStack>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptContent,id){if(IsNull(container))container=this.get_headElement();var$v_0=container.ownerDocument.createElement("script");container.appendChild($v_0);!isNullOrEmptyString(id)&&$v_0.setAttribute("id",id);$v_0.setAttribute("type","text/javascript");$v_0.text=scriptContent}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(container,scriptFile){var$v_0=scriptFile.toString();if(this.$4V_1($v_0))return;var$v_1=this.fetchExternalFile($v_0);this.addIncludeInline(container,$v_1,$v_0)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(uri,useInlineScripts,scriptLoaded){if(uri.get_path().toUpperCase()==="/_STATIC/_COMMON/SCRIPTS/GLOBAL.JS")uri=Mscrm.CrmUri.create("/_common/global.ashx");if(useInlineScripts)Mscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalSync(null,uri);elseMscrm.CrmHeader.get_scriptLoader().addIncludeExternalCallback(null,uri,scriptLoaded)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3){Mscrm.CrmHeader.setScriptFile(Mscrm.CrmUri.create($p1),true);for(var$v_0=window,$v_1=$p0.split("."),$v_2=0;$v_2<$v_1.length;$v_2++)if($v_0)$v_0=$v_0[$v_1[$v_2]];if(!IsNull($v_0)&&typeof$v_0===Mscrm.TypeNames.functionType){var$v_3=this.$CN_1($p2,$p3);return$v_0.apply(null,$v_3)}returnnull}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){var$v_0=this.$9w_1($p0.FunctionName,$p0.Library,$p0.Parameters,null);if(!IsNull($v_0)&&typeof$v_0===Mscrm.TypeNames.booleanType)return$v_0;elsereturn$p1}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){if(IsNull($p0))returnfalse;var$v_0=$p0.DefaultValue;switch($p0.RuleType){case8:$v_0=this.$Cz_1($p0);break;case1:$v_0=this.$D2_1($p0);break;case7:$v_0=this.$D3_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break;case4:$v_0=this.$D4_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break;case16:$v_0=this.$D5_1($p0);break;case2:$v_0=this.$D6_1($p0);break;case10:$v_0=this.$D7_1($p0);break;case19:$v_0=this.$D8_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break;case17:$v_0=this.$D9_1($p0);break;case12:$v_0=this.$DA_1($p0);break;case6:$v_0=this.$D1_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break;case5:$v_0=this.$DB_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break;case11:$v_0=this.$DC_1($p0);break;case3:$v_0=this.$DD_1($p0,$p0.DefaultValue);break}if(IsNull($v_0))$v_0=IsNull($p0.DefaultValue)?true:$p0.DefaultValue;if(!IsNull($p0.InvertResult)&&$p0.InvertResult)$v_0=!$v_0;return$v_0}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){var$v_0=this.getEnableRuleDefinition($p0,$p1);if(IsNull($v_0)||IsNull($v_0.Rules)||!$v_0.Rules.length)returntrue;for(var$v_1=true,$v_2=0;$v_1&&$v_2<$v_0.Rules.length;$v_2++)$v_1=$v_1&&this.$9v_1($v_0.Rules[$v_2]);return$v_1}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1){if(IsNull(Mscrm.RibbonCommands.enableRules))returntrue;var$v_0=this.getCommandDefinition($p0,$p1);if(IsNull($v_0))returntrue;var$v_1=$v_0.EnableRules;if(IsNull($v_1))returntrue;for(var$v_2=true,$v_3=0;$v_2&&$v_3<$v_1.length;$v_3++){var$v_4=$v_1[$v_3];if(IsNull($v_4)||!$v_4.length)continue;$v_2=$v_2&&this.$D0_1($v_4,$p1)}return$v_2}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){if(!this.$5T_1)returnfalse;var$v_0=this.parseCommandFromRibbon($p0),$v_1=this.$CH_1($v_0.command,$v_0.entityLogicalName);if($v_1&&!IsNull(this.$H_1.$5A_2[$p0]))$v_1=Mscrm.RibbonNavigationModel.shouldContextGroupBeShown($v_0,this.$H_1);elseif($v_1&&!IsNull(this.$H_1.$28_2[$p0]))$v_1=Mscrm.RibbonNavigationModel.shouldTabBeShown($p0,$v_0,this.$H_1);if(!IsNull(this.$H_1.$28_2[$p0]))this.$H_1.$28_2[$p0]=$v_1;return$v_1}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0){if(this.$1w_1&&!this.$1w_1.$3k_1)returnthis.$1w_1.canHandleCommand($p0);returnfalse}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(handler,commandId){returnhandler.canHandleCommand(commandId)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(commandId){var$v_0=this.$2R_0[commandId];if(CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($v_0))returnfalse;elseif(Array.isInstanceOfType($v_0)){for(var$v_1=$v_0,$v_2=0;$v_2<$v_1.length;$v_2++){var$v_3=$v_1[$v_2];if(this.callCommandHandlerForEnabled($v_3,commandId))returntrue}returnfalse}elsereturnthis.callCommandHandlerForEnabled($v_0,commandId)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(commandId,root){returnthis.$10_1.isCommandEnabled(commandId)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3){var$v_0=0,$v_1=this.$26_1.isRootCommandEnabled($p0,this);if($v_1)$v_0=1;if(CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined($p1)||!$p3&&!$v_1)return$v_0;if(this.$26_1.executeRootCommand($p1,$p2,null,this))$v_0|=2;return$v_0}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3){var$v_0=(this.$0_0.$As_1($p0,$p1,$p2,$p3)&1)>0;this.set_enabled($v_0);return$v_0}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){!CUI.ScriptUtility.isNullOrUndefined(this.$5_0.Command)&&this.pollForStateAndUpdateInternal(this.$5_0.Command,null,null,false)}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){this.$N_1.$Ef_0()}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){var$$enum_0=this.$6_0.getEnumerator();while($$enum_0.moveNext()){var$v_0=$$enum_0.get_current();$v_0.$48_0()}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){var$$enum_0=this.$6_0.getEnumerator();while($$enum_0.moveNext()){var$v_0=$$enum_0.get_current();$v_0.$48_0()}}</Function>
    <Function>anonymous(){var$$enum_0=this.$6_0.getEnumerator();while($$enum_0.moveNext()){var$v_0=$$enum_0.get_current();$v_0.$48_0()}}</Function>
   </CallStack>
  </ScriptErrorDetails>
  <ClientInformation>
   <BrowserUserAgent>Mozilla/5.0 (compatible; MSIE 9.0; Windows NT 6.1; WOW64; Trident/5.0; SLCC2; .NET CLR 2.0.50727; .NET CLR 3.5.30729; .NET CLR 3.0.30729; Media Center PC 6.0; InfoPath.3; .NET4.0C; .NET4.0E)</BrowserUserAgent>
   <BrowserLanguage>en-us</BrowserLanguage>
   <SystemLanguage>en-gb</SystemLanguage>
   <UserLanguage>en-gb</UserLanguage>
   <ScreenResolution>1463x823</ScreenResolution>
   <ClientName>Web</ClientName>
   <ClientTime>2013-09-26T14:27:54</ClientTime>
  </ClientInformation>
  <ServerInformation>
    <OrgLanguage>1033</OrgLanguage>
    <OrgCulture>6153</OrgCulture>
    <UserLanguage>1033</UserLanguage>
    <UserCulture>6153</UserCulture>
    <OrgID>{1757FAE8-2C1C-4992-958F-1819BBAF0D07}</OrgID>
    <UserID>{3EB16144-A4FE-E211-9EAD-3C4A92DBC8A2}</UserID>
    <CRMVersion>5.0.9690.5010</CRMVersion>
  </ServerInformation>
</CrmScriptErrorReport>
```

Any one can help? I`m stuck on this!

Comment: did you try adding a `;` to line 1 of `/userdefined/edit.aspx`? Shot in the dark here.

Comment: This is the CRM online solution so i cant have access to the edit.aspx page! What is more strange is this doesn't happen with some users!

Comment: you really are better off opening a ticket.  This appears to be a platform issue, meaning you will have a difficult time fixing it (unless you've been messing with the crmweb folder...in which case, you were asking for this...)

Comment: it's specific to a "userdefined" page, which is why it only affects some users. Something in your user defined page is borked.

Answer (score 0):

There is no solution, since CRM is online solution so we cant have access to the edit.aspx page! I ad to open a ticket on Microsoft Support page. The rollup did create an error, but for same cases this can help ([CRM 2013 custom code validation tool usage](http://social.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/b3744585-0b02-402f-9443-9ff6ed431c72/crm-2013-cutom-code-validation-tool-usage)), in my case dind! Thanks 1 million!